# Плавное появление без JS\jQuery

Tags: html, css, transition

Вопрос следующий, возможно ли плавное появление блока `dropdown` без использования JS jQuery и т.п.? Если да то как? `transition` не срабатывал...

```css
.menu:focus ~ .dropdown{
display: block;
}

.main-head .dropdown{
position: absolute;
margin-top: 85px;
right: 210px;
display: none;
}
```

```html
<header class="main-head">      
    <div id="logo">
        <p>Smart</p>
    </div>
    <button class="button menu">Кнопка</button>
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li>
            <a href="">Menu1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Menu2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Menu3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Menu4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`transition` не применим к свойству `display: none | block;`

**Вариант 1 `opacity`:**

```css
.menu:focus ~ .dropdown{
  opacity: 1;
}

.main-head .dropdown{
position: absolute;
margin-top: 85px;
right: 210px;
opacity: 0;
  
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<header class="main-head">      
    <div id="logo">
        <p>Smart</p>
    </div>
    <button class="button menu">Кнопка</button>
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li>
            <a href="">Menu1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Menu2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Menu3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Menu4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

**Вариант 2 `scale`:**

```css
.menu:focus ~ .dropdown{
 transform: scale(1);
}

.main-head .dropdown{
position: absolute;
margin-top: 85px;
right: 210px;

  transform: scale(0);
  
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<header class="main-head">      
    <div id="logo">
        <p>Smart</p>
    </div>
    <button class="button menu">Кнопка</button>
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li>
            <a href="">Menu1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Menu2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Menu3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Menu4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

**Вариант 3 `translateX`:**

```css
.menu:focus ~ .dropdown{
 transform: translateX(0%);
}

.main-head .dropdown{
position: absolute;
margin-top: 85px;
right: 210px;

  transform: translateX(-1000%);
  
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<header class="main-head">      
    <div id="logo">
        <p>Smart</p>
    </div>
    <button class="button menu">Кнопка</button>
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li>
            <a href="">Menu1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Menu2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Menu3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Menu4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

**Вариант 4 `translateY`:**

```css
.menu:focus ~ .dropdown{
 transform: translateY(0%);
}

.main-head .dropdown{
position: absolute;
margin-top: 85px;
right: 210px;

  transform: translateY(-1000%);
  
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<header class="main-head">      
    <div id="logo">
        <p>Smart</p>
    </div>
    <button class="button menu">Кнопка</button>
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li>
            <a href="">Menu1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Menu2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Menu3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Menu4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

**Вариант с `absolute`:**

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu:focus ~ .dropdown{
  right: 210px;
}

.main-head .dropdown{
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 85px;
  right: -9999px;  
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<header class="main-head">      
    <div id="logo">
        <p>Smart</p>
    </div>
    <button class="button menu">Кнопка</button>
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li>
            <a href="">Menu1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Menu2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Menu3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Menu4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

Answer (score 3):

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 85px;
  height: 0px;
  width: 100px;
}
@keyframes down1 {
  0% {
    height: 0;
  }
  10% {
    height: 10;
  }
  25% {
    height: 25px;
  }
  40% {
    height: 40;
  }
  50% {
    height: 50px;
  }
  60% {
    height: 60;
  }
  75% {
    height: 75px;
  }
  80% {
    height: 80;
  }
  100% {
    height: 100px;
  }
}

.menu:focus ~ .dropdown {
  outline: 1px solid #ccc;
  animation-name: down1;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<header class="main-head">
  <div id="logo">
    <p>Smart</p>
  </div>
  <button class="button menu">Кнопка</button>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <div>
      <a href="">Menu1</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="">Menu2</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="">Menu3</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="">Menu4</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте `@keyframes` при нажатии на `dropdown` `@keyframes` будет анимировать ваш `ul` .

Comment: допустим @keyframes, а если это не HTML5 и CSS3, а ниже...

Comment: не имеет значение потомушто browsers потдерживают css3 и HTML5